# How can I change location and the style of the table of content in laravel snappy

Tags: php, css, laravel, wkhtmltopdf

I am using laravel-snappy to covert the HTMl view to pdf but I want to change the location of the TOC and put it on page 3 also I want to change the font of the table of content, the color of the dotted lines, and the color of the headers ?

the options do not give me a full control of the style

```
 $pdf = \PDF::loadView('pdf-report.report', $data)
            ->setPaper('A4')
            ->setOption('cover', $cover_html)
            ->setOption('header-html', $html)
            ->setOption('header-spacing', 2)
            ->setOption('margin-top', 26.7)
            ->setOption('margin-left', 13)
            ->setOption('margin-bottom', 26.7)
            ->setOption('margin-right', 13)
            ->setOption('footer-right', utf8_decode('[page]'))
            ->setOption('toc', true)
            ->setOption('toc-level-indentation', 3);

            return $pdf->download($title);
```